# Downloaded bootstrap runs in firefox but not in chrome

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When i kept cdn links for bootstrap it ran just fine but when I downloaded bootstrap and kept in my project it works fine in  firefox but does not work properly in chrome like some functionality are there like when I  resize the browser the links goes and can be opened from navigation button. 
    [image: In chrome]
    [image: In Firefox]

```
    <!doctype HTML>
    {% load static %}
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">
    <title>Portfolio</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent1">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter-square"></i></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fab fa-github"></i></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
</header>
<!-- Optional JavaScript -->
<script src="{% static 'js/all.min.js' %}"></script>
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="{% static 'js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
```

My Project Structure

```
Porfolio
 -base
   -migrations
   -templates
      -base
        -base.html
 -portfolio
 -static
   -css
   -img
   -js
```

My settings

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/images/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
   os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]
```

Comment: I dont think that this issue is related to static files logic in Django. Could you please check in your google dev tools if the ressources are loaded correctly? If so, it is more like a css problem probably.

Comment: @Jonas I haven't added any CSS property I just have copy and pasted bootstrap navbar into base.html and yeah all the resources are loaded it's just that it works on firefox but does not work on chrome.

Comment: ok then it is a plain CSS/HTML/bootstrap issue and not related to Django. I edited your post therefor to get the correct attention so you will get a solution from the community shortly.

Comment: @Jonas thank you for your time for helping fix this problem I fixed it.

Comment: I don't know if it did not load properly or what I cut the header and saved then terminated the local host and again pasted the header part and started localhost again now it worked just fine.

Comment: restart your pc

Answer (score 3):

It's not issue related to static files logic in Django as Django dont server static files differently for different browser. It may be one of the reasons which are mentioned below:-

1)Probably your Google Chrome is using some cached files of the same name of bootstrap. This problem may be solved by refreshing the page by pressing `Ctrl+Shift+R` in chrome , it refreshes the page without using cached files or else u may even use incoginated mode in chrome
2)There are some styles which are unique for firefox and opera like browser's but i dont think there would be that change in two different browser any way it might be a reason.